# Como validar la descarga de un archivo cuando no hay datos, usando spring?

Tags: java, spring, csv, descarga

tengo el siguiente método en el controller que pasa parámetros a un método del servicio para hacer la búsqueda del query, y la informacion la descarga en un archivo de texto csv

```html
@RequestMapping(value= "/views/formulario", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="text/csv")
public void obtieneDatos(@ModelAttribute("consultaForm") Factura fact, Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
   
   String id = fact.getId();
   String cvePag=fact.getClavePago();
   Date fecha = fact.getFechaInicial();

   List<Factura> factList = obtieneInfoService.consultaDatos(id, cvePag, fecha);

   response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/csv");
   response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=export.csv");
   try {
       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       out.write("nombreCol1;nombreCol2;...;nombreColN;");
       out.write("\n");

      if(factList !=null && !factList.isEmpty){
   for(Factura result: factList) {
           out.write(result.toCSVRepresentation());
           out.write("\n");
   }
  }
       out.flush();
       out.close();
   } catch (IOException ix) {
       throw new RuntimeException("There was an error while retrieving CSV data", ix);
   } 
  }
```

En mi formulario tengo los campos y un boton de buscar, a la hora de dar click en el boton se descarga automáticamente el archivo de texto, aunque no le meta valores a los inputs, o si los lleno con datos que no tienen informacion, aun asi lo descarga, y lo que quiero hacer es que eso no pase, que si le doy click en el boton sin llenar los campos, me mande un mensaje que diga, debes llenar los campos, y  si los lleno y no hay informacion con esos datos, que diga no se encontraron registros.

En mi codigo del controller, puse un if para la lista, que si es diferente de null, haga la iteracion, y trate de meterle un else y que diga no hay datos, y me lo pinta en consola, pero aun asi descarga el archivo,
como le puedo hacer, para que solo lo descargue cuando hay datos?

Este es mi codigo de la vista

```html
function consultar(){
var valido = true;
var valId = document.getElementaryById('idPago').value;
var valClavePago = document.getElementaryById('clavePago').value;
var valFecha = document.getElementaryById('fechaPago').value;

if(valId.trim() =="" && valClavePago.trim() == "" && valFecha.trim() == ""){

  HelperDialogs.mostrar("Debes ingresar al menos un valor");
  valido = false;
}
  return valido;
}


<form: form id="consulta" modelAttribute="consultaForm">
  <tr>
    <td><label>ID/label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text"  id="idPago" path="id"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td><label>CLAVE PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="clavePago" path="clavePago"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
   
   
   <tr>
    <td><label>FECHA PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="fechaPago" path="fechaPago"/></td>
    <input type="submit" onclick="consultar()"></input>
   </tr>
</form:form>
```

que valida que los campos no esten vacios al momento de dar click en el boton, pero al mismo tiempo hace la descarga del archivo,
como puedo controlar eso?
He visto que usan ajax, pero la verdad no tengo idea, alguien podria ayudarme?, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Sencillamente espera a ver si hay datos ANTES DE AÑADIR LOS *HEADER*S.

Si hay datos, añades los headers y escribes en `out` el contenido del fichero; si no hay datos pues lo que decidas:

- Escribir el HTML de un mensaje de error ("`NO HAY DATOS")
- Hacer un redirect a una página de error.
- ...